# Difference in inflating views

Tags: android, layout, view, android-context, layout-inflater

Wanted to ask. What's the difference between:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

And:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
```

?

Comment: There is no difference,  check `from` source code

Comment: @Selvin, could you share it with me?

Comment: What for? Android is opensource and it can be easily found.

Comment: @Selvin, Ok, thank you)

Comment: http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi, Oh, nice, Thank you)

Comment: The only practical difference is that the first example uses `getBaseContext()`, which is almost always *not* what you want. `Activity` is a `Context` with a theme. By using its base context you'll lose the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is not that big.
`LayoutInflater#from(Context context)` source code:

```
    public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (LayoutInflater == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
        }
        return LayoutInflater;
    }
```

So, `LayoutInflater#from` inside uses the same `context.getSystemService`.

Reference: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.from%28android.content.Context%29